# Replacing subexpression by a symbol?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a 3x3 matrix, of which I compute inverse. The inverse can be written legibly only when some subexpressions are replaced by new symbols, because they appear multiple times. Can I have sympy try hard to find those subexpressions and replace them? I tried the following, without success:

```
from sympy import *

Ex, Ez, nuxy, nuxz = symbols('E_x E_z nu_xy nu_xz')

# compliance matrix for cross-anisotropic material
compl = Matrix([[1/Ex, -nuxy/Ex, -nuxz/Ez],
                [-nuxy/Ex, 1/Ex, -nuxz/Ez],
                [-nuxz/Ex, -nuxz/Ex, 1/Ez]])

# stiffness matrix
stiff = compl.inv()

# symbols I want to introduce 
m, e = symbols('m e')  

meSubs = {Ex/Ez: e, (1 - nuxy - 2*e*nuxz**2): m}  # instead of these subexpressions

# stiff.simplify() returns None, is that a bug? that's why I apply simplify together with subs here:
stiff.applyfunc(lambda x: simplify(x.subs(meSubs)))
print stiff
```

Using sympy 0.6.7 (I could upgrade, if needed).

***EDIT:***

I upgraded to 0.7.1-git (cf9c01f8f9b4b749a7f59891f546646e4b38e580 to be precise), and run (thanks to @PreludeAndFugue for suggestion):

```
from sympy import *
Ex,Ez,nuxy,nuxz,m=symbols('E_x E_z nu_xy nu_xz m')
compl=Matrix([[1/Ex,-nuxy/Ex,-nuxz/Ez],[-nuxy/Ex,1/Ex,-nuxz/Ez],[-nuxz/Ex,-nuxz/Ex,1/Ez]])
stiff=compl.inv()
stiff.simplify()
stiff.subs({-nuxy-2*nuxz**2+1:m})    # tried other rearrangements of the equality, as well, same result.
stiff.applyfunc(lambda x: together(expand(x)))
pprint(stiff)
```

obtaining

```
⎡              ⎛    2    ⎞                         ⎛            2⎞                              ⎤
⎢           Eₓ⋅⎝ν_xz  - 1⎠                     -Eₓ⋅⎝-ν_xy - ν_xz ⎠                 Eₓ⋅ν_xz      ⎥
⎢ ──────────────────────────────────   ────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────⎥
⎢     2              2         2             2              2         2                    2    ⎥
⎢ ν_xy  + 2⋅ν_xy⋅ν_xz  + 2⋅ν_xz  - 1   - ν_xy  - 2⋅ν_xy⋅ν_xz  - 2⋅ν_xz  + 1  -ν_xy - 2⋅ν_xz  + 1⎥
⎢                                                                                               ⎥
⎢            ⎛            2⎞                         ⎛    2    ⎞                                ⎥
⎢        -Eₓ⋅⎝-ν_xy - ν_xz ⎠                      Eₓ⋅⎝ν_xz  - 1⎠                   Eₓ⋅ν_xz      ⎥
⎢────────────────────────────────────   ──────────────────────────────────   ───────────────────⎥
⎢      2              2         2           2              2         2                     2    ⎥
⎢- ν_xy  - 2⋅ν_xy⋅ν_xz  - 2⋅ν_xz  + 1   ν_xy  + 2⋅ν_xy⋅ν_xz  + 2⋅ν_xz  - 1   -ν_xy - 2⋅ν_xz  + 1⎥
⎢                                                                                               ⎥
⎢              E_z⋅ν_xz                              E_z⋅ν_xz                  E_z⋅(ν_xy - 1)   ⎥
⎢        ───────────────────                   ───────────────────           ────────────────── ⎥
⎢                      2                                     2                            2     ⎥
⎣        -ν_xy - 2⋅ν_xz  + 1                   -ν_xy - 2⋅ν_xz  + 1           ν_xy + 2⋅ν_xz  - 1 ⎦
```

Hm, so why does not get "-ν_xy - 2⋅ν_xz² + 1" replaced with m?

Comment: Note that `stiff.simplify()` simplifies `stiff` inplace, so returns `None`. Compare with, for example, `list.sort()`.

Comment: Sympy's `pprint` function can be used to print a prettified version.

Comment: @PreludeAndFugue: thanks for the `simplify()` thing... could've checked.

Comment: All the core developers are here: http://groups.google.com/group/sympy/topics. You should get good answers from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your substitutions fail because the patterns do not exist in your matrix. Let's look at them one at a time:

1. There is no Ex/Ez ratio; `x.subs(x/y, z)` is unchanged
2. You have an extra `e` that appears in `1 - nuxy - 2*e*nuxz**2` so that expression is never matched, either.

@asmeurer showed that the literal `1 - nuxy - 2*nuxz**2` can be replaced, but it appears, too, as a factor in some denominators. The more complicated replacement can be done by checking if the patterns evenly divides an expression.

Let's make a function that will do that replacement:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = 1 - nuxy - 2*e*nuxz**2
>>> def do(x):
...    w, r = div(x, t)
...    if not r:
...        return m*w
...    return x
```

Now we will apply this to each element of the matrix:

```
>>> stiff.applyfunc(lambda x: factor_terms(bottom_up(x, do)))
Matrix([
[   -E_x*(nu_xz**2 - 1)/(m*(nu_xy + 1)), E_x*(nu_xy + nu_xz**2)/(m*(nu_xy + 1)),        E_x*nu_xz/m],
[E_x*(nu_xy + nu_xz**2)/(m*(nu_xy + 1)),    -E_x*(nu_xz**2 - 1)/(m*(nu_xy + 1)),        E_x*nu_xz/m],
[                           E_z*nu_xz/m,                            E_z*nu_xz/m, -E_z*(nu_xy - 1)/m]])
```

With complicated expressions/matrices, it is sometimes good to get an overview of the structure by using `cse`:

```
>>> cse(stiff)
([(x0, nu_xz**2), (x1, E_x*x0), (x2, 2*x0), (x3, x2 - 1), (x4, 1/(nu_xy**2 + nu_xy*x2 + x3)), (x5, x4*(-E_x + x1)), (x6, x4*(-E_x*nu_xy - x1)), (x7, 1/(nu_xy + x3)), (x8, nu_xz*x7), (x9, -E_x*x8), (x10, -E_z*x8)], [Matrix([
[ x5,  x6,                   x9],
[ x6,  x5,                   x9],
[x10, x10, x7*(E_z*nu_xy - E_z)]])])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if using 0.6.7 is a problem - but updating to 0.7.1 is recommended.

When I look at `stiff`, I can't see the subsitutions in `meSubs` being useful. After creating `stiff`, I did the following:

```
stiff.simplify()
stiff = stiff.subs({2*nuxz**2: 1 - nuxy - m})
stiff = stiff.applyfunc(lambda x: together(expand(x)))
pprint(stiff)
```

The output isn't too bad:

```
[      /     2    \        /             2\                  ]
[  E_x*\nu_xz  - 1/    E_x*\nu_xy + nu_xz /     E_x*nu_xz    ]
[  ----------------    --------------------     ---------    ]
[   m*(-nu_xy - 1)        m*(nu_xy + 1)             m        ]
[                                                            ]
[    /             2\        /     2    \                    ]
[E_x*\nu_xy + nu_xz /    E_x*\nu_xz  - 1/       E_x*nu_xz    ]
[--------------------    ----------------       ---------    ]
[   m*(nu_xy + 1)         m*(-nu_xy - 1)            m        ]
[                                                            ]
[     E_z*nu_xz             E_z*nu_xz        E_z*(-nu_xy + 1)]
[     ---------             ---------        ----------------]
[         m                     m                   m        ]
```

expand: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/core.html?highlight=expand#sympy.core.function.expand

together: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/polys/reference.html?highlight=together#sympy.polys.rationaltools.together

Comment: Yeah, the subs stuff above doesn't work that way in 0.6.7 (at least for me, probably because it doesn't recognize the nu in .subs() but does when making the symbol in the first place). Upgrading to 0.7.1 is a good idea regardless.

Comment: I tried with the latest git version, and put it as edit to the question. Perhaps is my machine cursed?

Answer (score 0):

It does get replaced, but `subs` does not work mutably on Matrices.  `applyfunc` doesn't work mutably either, unfortunately.   I get

```
In [10]: pprint(stiff.subs({-nuxy-2*nuxz**2+1:m}))
⎡               ⎛     2    ⎞                            ⎛              2⎞                            ⎤
⎢            Eₓ⋅⎝nu_xz  - 1⎠                        -Eₓ⋅⎝-nu_xy - nu_xz ⎠                Eₓ⋅nu_xz    ⎥
⎢ ──────────────────────────────────────   ────────────────────────────────────────      ────────    ⎥
⎢      2                2          2              2                2          2             m        ⎥
⎢ nu_xy  + 2⋅nu_xy⋅nu_xz  + 2⋅nu_xz  - 1   - nu_xy  - 2⋅nu_xy⋅nu_xz  - 2⋅nu_xz  + 1                  ⎥
⎢                                                                                                    ⎥
⎢             ⎛              2⎞                           ⎛     2    ⎞                               ⎥
⎢         -Eₓ⋅⎝-nu_xy - nu_xz ⎠                        Eₓ⋅⎝nu_xz  - 1⎠                   Eₓ⋅nu_xz    ⎥
⎢────────────────────────────────────────   ──────────────────────────────────────       ────────    ⎥
⎢       2                2          2            2                2          2              m        ⎥
⎢- nu_xy  - 2⋅nu_xy⋅nu_xz  - 2⋅nu_xz  + 1   nu_xy  + 2⋅nu_xy⋅nu_xz  + 2⋅nu_xz  - 1                   ⎥
⎢                                                                                                    ⎥
⎢               E_z⋅nu_xz                                 E_z⋅nu_xz                  -E_z⋅(nu_xy - 1)⎥
⎢               ─────────                                 ─────────                  ────────────────⎥
⎣                   m                                         m                             m        ⎦
```

There are plans to make Matrix immutable by default, and then make MutableMatrix work completely in place on all operations. See https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3410. But it hasn't happened yet.